# expressjs - mongoDb return nested subArray

Tags: javascript, mongodb, api, express

im trying to create a seprate route in my api for a subArray from a nested array. using expressJs.

categories array:

```
const Categories = [
{
    _id: 's654fs54s6d4f'
    title: 'category 1',
    SubCats: [
        {
            _id: 'jhgfsf68746'
            name: 'subcat 1',
            image: '/assets/images/vr-box-6203301_1920.jpg',
        },
        {
            _id: 'vb40n5b4vn'
            name: 'subcat 2',
            image: '/assets/images/galaxy-s20_highlights_kv_00.jpg',
        },
    ]
},
]
```

categoryModel:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const Catschema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    image: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
})

const CategorySchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        title: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        SubCats: [Catschema]
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
    }
)

const Category = mongoose.model('Category', CategorySchema)

export default Category
```

categoryController:

this would return the whole array

```
const getCategories = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
   const categories = await Category.find({})
   res.json(categories)
})
```

i want to return 'SubCats' array.

tried this but getting "SubCats is not defined".

```
const getSubCategories = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
   const subcategories = await Category.find({SubCats})
   res.json(subcategories)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find()` returns an array and it takes in an object to query the db. In your question you used `Category.find({SubCats})` which is `Category.find({SubCats: SubCats})`, which SubCats is not defined.

I think what you are looking for is `Category.find().select('SubCats')`, this will return an array of Categories with SubCats only.

Comment: thanks it worked.  also there as there a way to get them by id. for example: `const subcategory = await Category.find({}).select('SubCats').findById(req.params.id)`

Comment: `Category.findById(req.params.id).select('SubCats')`

Comment: thanks for the reply. but i meant getting by id for subcats items. example. getting 'subcat 1' by  its id 'jhgfsf68746'.

Comment: @aboodalwa7sh i believe you can do 
`Category.find({'SubCats.id': req.params.id}).select('SubCats')` ? (Not tested)